# Does callBatchTasks (from ORMLite) run in a separate thread?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to manage my database on my android app and it has been working pretty well.  Occasionally though, I'll get an exception containing about a constraint when I try to update the data.  The exception helped me trace it to where I am calling [callBatchTasks()](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#callBatchTasks%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29).

It's actually a series of 3 calls at that point.  The first calls 2 update Table1 and Table2.  The last call updates a table (Table3) that is used to specify the relationship between Table1 and Table2 (and therefore has constraints).  This is the one that gets the exception.

```
table1Dao.callBatchTasks(table1task);
table2Dao.callBatchTasks(table2task);
table3Dao.callBatchTasks(table3task);  // Exception here
```

Since the tasks implement `callable` I'm thinking that each runs on a separate thread.  So if the table3task gets ahead of either of the other ones, it runs into a constraint issue.  Is this true?  If so, what's the recommend workaround so that they execute in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you fixed your problem but I thought I'd answer with more information.

`Dao.callBatchTasks(...)` has nothing to do with threads.  The source for all [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) classes is available through the source jars or online.  Looking at the [source for BaseDaoImpl.callBatchTasks(...)](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/code/HEAD/tree/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.java) which calls through to [`StatementExecutor.callBatchTasks(...)`](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/code/HEAD/tree/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/StatementExecutor.java), it:

1. Turns off auto-commit (using an android transaction)
2. Calls the `Callable.call()` method that is passed in as the argument to `callbatchTasks(...)`
3. Restored auto-commit (closing the android transaction)

Comment: That's what I was thinking (after figuring out my issue).  Anyways, thanks for the response!  I'm marking it as the answer since it actually answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue.  It was a threading thing, but it was in my logic.  Two calls to the same update task were being made right after each other, creating 2 threads.  One would try inserting things into table3 when the other already had, which caused the error.

It seems like `callBatchTasks` doesn't run in its own thread then, since when I fixed that issue it resolved the errors.